# Which files can VSCode read?

Tags: security, privacy, visual-studio-code

If I open a folder using VSCode, it can read the files in that folder. However, can it read the files outside that folder? I can use the terminal inside VSCode and if I run `cd ..` command, I can operate files outside that folder.

What I want to know is not about file type, but about range. Is it possible for VSCode or extensions installed in it to read a file outside the working directory and send the content to someone's server?

Comment: You ask about VSCode, but then say "someone" – are you asking if Microsoft can extract the files off your computer, or if some third party can? How would the third party be involved in this scenario?

Comment: @EzekielElin I'll edit it. I meant both Microsoft and the developers of extensions.

Comment: I'm not gonna write up a full answer since I don't know the specifics - but yes VSCode and any extension can access your file system with wide access. Anything listed in System Preferences > Privacy is a restricted area and can only be accessed with permission.